# Chloramines & Nitrogen Trichloride vs Stainless Steel

Tags: redox, halides, safety, water-treatment, explosives

We've recently experienced excessive corrosion on stainless steel within indoor pool environments. We believe this is due to chloramine (gasses) in the atmosphere. To test this, I plan to create a small, closed environment (loosely sealed to contain gas but limit pressure buildup), in which I'll mix a solution to create some chloramines and hang material samples.

I assume (not from chemical background) that introducing pool chlorine (granular [calcium hypochlorite](https://www.bunnings.com.au/hy-clor-500g-super-shock-granular-pool-chlorine_p0074612) 70%) and ammonia (as [cloudy ammonia](https://www.woolworths.com.au/shop/productdetails/90685/supreme-cloudy-ammonia) NH3 20g/L) to water, will kick most of this off. Attempts to maximise chloramines (Fig.1) will hopefully be achieved by keeping chlorine levels below breakpoint (Red local minimum - Fig.2)

[image: Figure 1 - Choramines]

[image: Breakpoint Chlorination]

I am slightly concerned after reading some [articles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrogen_trichloride) and [forums](http://www.sciencemadness.org/talk/viewthread.php?tid=2079) stating nitrogen trichloride (trichloramine) can be explosive. This [factsheet](https://www.health.nsw.gov.au/environment/factsheets/Pages/breakpoint-chlorination.aspx) states its only formed 'after breakpoint'. Additionally, some say '[in sunlight, will decompose](https://www.sciencemadness.org/smwiki/index.php/Nitrogen_trichloride)', whilst others show it [exploding in sunlight](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6I6zbiHyf-A)

Can anyone provide advice on how to safety generate monochloramine and dichloramine gasses without generating dangerous amounts of nitrogen trichloride?

I have an (*ancient*) Palintest photometer to monitor free/total chlorine but does not display ammonia.

Comment: [At low pH values, nitrogen trichloride dominates and at pH 3–5 dichloramine dominates. These equilibria are disturbed by the irreversible decomposition of both compounds](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/47121/mixing-bleach-and-ammonia/126824#126824)

Comment: A dilute solution is irritating not explosive. But don't try to concentrate it or extract it.

Comment: @matt_black for clarity we are trying to encourage some chloramine gasses buy placing the container in the sun with a glass top and some reflecting panels to introduce some heat, like a low-powered solar cooker. The unit is not well sealed so pressure buildup should be able to escape. I'm curious though, at what point does encouraging some generation (and degradation in UV) become 'concentrating'? I currently have no means of measuring specific chloramines, only 'Combined Chlorine'

Comment: I'm also very new to the StackExchange, can someone please explain why I'm receiving downvotes? Would love to learn more and better contribute to these forums.

Comment: For starters it's a Q&A site, not a forum... While pure NCl3 is explosive (kinda surprisingly) its dilute solutions aren't. I still don't get what you're trying to achieve there, and the post requires some copyediting.

Comment: @Kuhrta if you want to know what not to do you should watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mV_daaldE_I)

Comment: @Mithoron thanks for clarifying. I've edited the post but was unsure if information or clarity was the lacking component. Also, when you say 'dilute solution' does this include vapour state in a high humidity environment?

Comment: Why chances of "boom" would be really small, all these compounds are dangerous. I wouldn't try such experiment. Better analyse water (or air), check quality of steel and compare with data that are already available.

Comment: @Mithoron part of the testing is comparative between specific coatings/treatments to the steel, to see how they interact within a high chloride/choramine environment. This paper [Stress-Corrosion Cracking of Austenitic Stainless Steel in Swimming Pools](https://nickelinstitute.org/media/8daa77b1620dde6/14015_ambient_temperaturestress_corrosioncrackingofausteniticstainlesssteelinswimmingpools.pdf), found that it's a unique phenomenon and were unable to replicate in lab conditions.

Comment: It seems like the chloramines/chlorides attack/crack the chromium oxide layer that protects austenitic stainless steels. Thus, existing literature regarding corrosion of stainless steels and other materials (predominantly quantified by salt-spray testing) will not be situationally accurate. Our company has taken that approach so far (49-years strong) but still seeing issues.

Comment: Fair enough, I guess, but you'd have to be real careful with concentrations, pressure, gas removal, etc. etc.

Comment: Careful is the name of our game. To monitor this i've still got some queries (Edited in Post) RE: PPM vs mg/L and 'Molar Ratio'